# Sort Array results based on variable Algorithm - MYSQL & PHP

Tags: mysql, algorithm, timestamp

I have an array nested within a PHP while loop that outputs a set of forum posts a number of times. I want to sort the array results based on an algorithm - however I do not want to hardcode the algorithm so I can test different variables at a later date. NB - I'm not looking to sort the items within the array, but rather the final output which when looped will output the array 20+ times.

Currently I have 2 Tables - the Forum table with loads of rows (3000 +):

```
id     |    name     |     date_add     |     votes    |    ...     |
1      |  Test Name  |    1234567890    |       2      |    ...     |
...    |     ...     |       ...        |      ...     |    ...     |
```

The other table contains the Algorithm variables that I want to pass through to the calculation and has only 1 row:

```
id     |   vote_reduction   |  time_variable    |     gravity    |
1      |         1          |        2          |      1.8       |
```

The specific algorithm I'm using sorts the information based on how log it has been live (in hours), how many votes it has and the gravity factor makes it more sensitive to time. In full:
(votes - vote_reduction)/((Hours Live + time_variable) ^ gravity)

So far I've managed to get this far, and something is going wrong but I can't quite figure it out:

```
SELECT forum.*,
((forum.votes - algorithm.vote_reduction)/POW(((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, SYSDATE(), forum.date_add)) + algorithm.time_variable),algorithm.gravity)) AS algorithm.al,
forum.name, forum.id
FROM forum as forum 
LEFT JOIN algorithm AS algorithm ON (algorithm.id='1')
ORDER BY algorithm.al
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "Something is going wrong" is not quite an explanation of the problem. Can you be more specific where the problem is?

Comment: Edit - adjusted the code slightly. The problem is that the code executes OK, but the new column that's added based on the alias "algorithm.al" contains no data - i.e. the calculation is not actually taking place. And therefore when I try to sort the results using ORDER BY algorithm.al nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in the code as follows:

1. Making an alias with the name "algorithm" clashes with a MySQL
   clause also called ALGORITHM
2. The calculation (at least the way it is
       edited above) creates too many values in the POW clause
3. Encapsulating all declared aliases in ' ' makes the code more full
       proof - but the ORDER BY clause doesn't like quotation marks (so remove them there)
4. The SYSDATE() and forum.date_add fields are in different formats -
   the latter being a timestamp

To fix:

```
SELECT forum.*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, from_unixtime(bd.date_add), NOW()) as 'timedif'
((forum.votes - alg.vote_reduction)/POW(('timedif' + alg.time_variable),alg.gravity)) AS 'al'
FROM forum AS forum
LEFT JOIN algorithm AS 'alg' ON (alg.id='1')
ORDER BY al
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the results of the algorithm, but the query returns a result for al if you just remove algorithm. from algorithm.al.  I don't think you can make a column alias that acts like it's part of a table.  What's confusing me is that you say that it's running on your machine.  It's not running on SQL Fiddle and is throwing an error.

```
SELECT forum.*,
((forum.votes - algorithm.vote_reduction)/POW(((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, SYSDATE(), forum.date_add)) + algorithm.time_variable),algorithm.gravity)) AS al
FROM forum AS forum
LEFT JOIN algorithm AS algorithm ON (algorithm.id='1')
ORDER BY al
```

[Link to SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c4ba/2)

Comment: Cheers Brian. I've been fiddling with this and have found the problem - this was part of it though. Thanks!